# How to get currentDate in English only instead of other language user set in iPhone?

Tags: swift, datetime

I'm getting dates from device like this.

```
var today: String {
    let date = Date()
    let df = DateFormatter()
    df.dateFormat = DATE_FORMAT
    return df.string(from: date)
}

var yesterday: String {
    let date = Date()
    guard let yesterday = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: date) else { return "" }
    let df = DateFormatter()
    df.dateFormat = DATE_FORMAT
    return df.string(from: yesterday)
}

var tomorrow: String {
    let date = Date()
    guard let tomorrow = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: date) else { return "" }
    let df = DateFormatter()
    df.dateFormat = DATE_FORMAT
    return df.string(from: tomorrow)
}
```

But when user changed device language. The date values are also changed.

[image][image]

What I need is pure english like "**2022-05-07**". Any advice?

Comment: The user's preferences don't adapt to your code. Your code should adapt to the user's preferences.

Comment: @KenWhite, I know that. That's why i'm posting this to change my code.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by adding following code to dateformat.

```
df.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "EN") as Locale
```

This happen because NSDate takes user's number option from device.

[image]